# Is there a reason my html isn't rendering?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm completely stuck. All of my html documents are validated and properly referenced to each other, but when I load the primary html, it doesn't render.

My objective is to have a page with two sides: The left side which displays a default image and caption, and the right side which includes a button to load a different random image of five and caption on the left side via different html documents.

I'm making different sides with "iframes."

Also how do change the width of the iframes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Free Jokes!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Justin Partovi, CS80 1184, Summer 2013">
        <link href="final%20project.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head> 

    <body>
        <h1 id="shadow">Welcome to Free Jokes!</h1>
        <iframe id="left" src="left.html"></iframe>
        <iframe id="right" src="right.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The left side:

(Please let me know if there is a better way to accomplish my objective other than the way I am doing now)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your Joke!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script>
        var randomnumber

        function clickForJoke() {
        randomnumber=math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 15);

        switch ( randomnumber ) {
        case 1:
            window.open( "joke1.html", target="right" );
            break;
        case 2:
            window.open( "joke2.html", target="right" );
            break;
        case 3:
            window.open( "joke3.html", target="right" );
            break;
        case 4:
            window.open( "joke4.html", target="right" );
            break;
        case 5:
            window.open( "joke5.html", target="right" );
            break;

        default:
            window.open( "joke.html", target="right" );
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

The right side:

(Did I make the button incorrectly?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Final project</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="final%20project.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" id="jokeButton" name="jokeButton" onclick="clickForJoke">Click for your joking pleasure!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The default image and cation:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Default joke</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="final%20project.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <p><img alt src = "laughing%20gif.gif"></p>
        <p><b>Click the button to the right to get a free joke!</b></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I didn't make the five other html documents yet.

Comment: There are multiple problems here, first is you are trying to access a function written in another `iframe` which is not allowed, second the function syntax is wrong - you are missing `}}` at the end

Comment: would you want the joke.html to open in the left panel

Comment: Yes. That was my intention. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with the button on right iframe trying to invoke a javascript function on the left iframe.

Each iframe operates in it's own process space and woudln't have direct access.

`parent.iframes["LeftIFrameName"].functionName` is the way to go...
which in your case would be `parent.iframes["left"].clickForJoke()` for the button onclick function

Comment: I changed 'clickForJoke' to 'parent.iframes["left"].clickForJoke()' but it still doesn't respond. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Arun pointed few syntax errors. Did you fix those? Could you just see what javascript error you could see on the error console?

Comment: I did fix them, but it's still unresponsive.

Comment: I switched my iframes to divs my switching '<iframe id="left" src="left.html"></iframe>' to ' <div id="left" src="left.html"></div>'and the button onclick function back to 'clickForJoke()'.

Comment: Not sure why the prev line was not working. I tried now. Use this -- **parent.window.frames["left"].clickForJoke();**. To ensure that the communication between the iframes work, please try first with some simple alert in your clickForJoke() function rather than testing the actual functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just control a different iframe from another iframe. You have to invoke it from the parent.

```
<button type="button" id="jokeButton" name="jokeButton" onclick="parent.iframes['left'].clickForJoke();">Click for your joking pleasure!</button>
```

**Suggestion:**

The purpose you are doing right now does not require you to use two iframe. It can be on the same utilizing AJAX. Here is an example:

First, let's add number of pages in an array

```
var pages = array("joke1.html", "joke2.html", ....);
```

Lets create a container that shows this page and add a button on the right

```
<div id="pageLoadArea"></div>
<div id="buttonArea"> 
    <a href="#" id="loadPage">Load Page</a>
</div>
```

Now, lets create a function which loads a random page on the div `pageLoadArea`

```
function loadPage() {
   page = pages[Math.floor(Math.random()*pages.length)];
   $("#pageLoadArea").load(page);
}
```

Now, lets executing this function when the page load and the button is clicked

```
$(function() {
    loadPage();
    $("#loadPage").on('click', loadPage);
});
```

Its Done. Just do some styling and it is done.

Comment: Yea, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

To change the size of the iframes you can use css:

```
<iframe id="left" src="left.html" style="width:50%"></iframe>
<iframe id="right" src="right.html" style="width: 50%"></iframe>
```

You'll probably need to float or arrange them in your own way to have them side by side.

It looks like your right iframe's document is calling a function that is defined in your left frame. When you have iframes pages within them practically exists in different space and there's also limited amount of information you can even feedback to the parent frame.

What you may actually want to do is scrape the iframes and just use divs or something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GhCAg/

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments

**Left**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
        <title>Your Joke!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
```

**Right**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Final project</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="final%20project.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" id="jokeButton" name="jokeButton" onclick="clickForJoke()">Click for your joking pleasure!</button>
        <script>
          var randomnumber

          function clickForJoke() {
              randomnumber=Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 15);

              switch ( randomnumber ) {
                  case 1:
                      window.open( "joke1.html", target="left" );
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      window.open( "joke2.html", target="left" );
                      break;
                  case 3:
                      window.open( "joke3.html", target="left" );
                      break;
                  case 4:
                      window.open( "joke4.html", target="left" );
                      break;
                  case 5:
                      window.open( "joke5.html", target="left" );
                      break;

                  default:
                      window.open( "joke.html", target="left" );
              }
          }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/81c1OKJThK8oPZHFthi7?p=preview)